# How can I add remove icon on Fabric element Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I'm using fabric in my react app. I have a button which add text to canvas. Now I want to set remove icon on top left of fabric Text and remove that text when clicked on icon Reactjs? I exactly don't know how to handle event listeners when click on canvas elements.

```
import React from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';


class Designer extends React.Component {


    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate ');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Make a New Canvas
        this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('meCanvas', {
            preserveObjectStacking: true,
            height: 812,
            width: 375,
            backgroundColor: 'gray'
        });

        let rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 150,
            fill: 'red',
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        });

        this.__canvas.add(rect);
    }

    addText() {
        let newID = new Date().getTime().toString().substr(5);
        let text = new fabric.IText('текст', {
            fontFamily: 'arial black',
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            myid: newID,
            objecttype: 'text'
        });


        this.__canvas.add(text);
        //this.addLayer(newID, 'text');
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render');
        return (
            <div>
                <button id="texts" onClick={() => this.addText()}>
                    TEXT PLEASE
                </button>
                <canvas id="meCanvas" ref="myFabric" onClick={console.log('onClick')} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Designer;
```

Comment: A canvas is a bunch of pixels, so you need to do a coordinate check. If you use `onClick={e => this.handleCanvasClick(e)}` and add `handleCanvasClick(e) { ... }` to your component, you can use `e.clientX/Y` to grab the coordinates.

Comment: onClick event is not working

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you need `e.nativeEvent.clientX`: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-grass-hkvkz

Comment: Sorry i didn't got it, can u elaborate bit more

Comment: Thanks I saw sandbox example, it is giving me coordinates in that canvas but i want to detect when user clicks on corner of Text and remove it.

Comment: Yeah, you need to figure out the coordinates of the corner square, then compare that against the coordinates of the click. There's no shortcut here, unless fabric supports detecting clicks on added stuff.

Comment: Well I have copied exactly your code from sandbox and pasted in my app but in there handlecanvasclick is not working

Comment: after removing componendDidMount, it is now handling click events. Why is that?

Comment: Put the exact code you have in the question or I can't help you.